# Streaming video fails to display page

Tags: streaming-video, chromium

YouTube is one of the top websites to view streaming videos. Oh well. It's not working on my RPi.

I have no idea if this question is any relevant to the Raspberry Pi, but I'm asking it anyway.

So, after multiple attempts (All failed) to watch streaming video, I kind of got bored of seeing that "Aw snap!" page. And, it all seemed to start happening when I reinstalled Raspbian and overwrote all existing data.

But  here's where I get confused:

It seems to be that either the web browser can't display the graphics and code of a streaming video (I think that's unlikely), or my RPi is the one that can't display videos (Probably). Either way, it does look like my Raspberry Pi is the one with the problems, as most of the web browsers on my Personal Computer and Mobile Devices are more than capable of displaying streaming video.

Other variables to consider when answering this question:

- It's only about a graphics displaying problem here. If I load up the video and the quickly leave the page to another tab (Not closing the webpage the streaming video is on), I can hear the audio of the vid, but the moment I return: "Aw, snap!"
- Also, by creating another internal RPi account, I can actually view streaming video with no problem.
- Please do not suggest I reinstall Raspbian unless it's absolutely necessary. I'm kind of tired of getting back all my data.
- I'm using the default Chromium browser.

Comment: **OBS this will erase the users chromium settings.** You could try to reinstall the Chromium browser. And after removing it erase the folder ~/.config where your Chromium settings are. And then install Chromium again

Comment: Another way could be to start Chromium with logging, https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging